# Jquery mobile - div content bind scroll not working the first time but after refreshing the page it works

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

```
<div  data-role="page" id="one" data-theme="a" >
    <div  data-role="content" id="content">
       <script type="text/javascript" >

         $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#content').bind('scroll', function () {  
                alert(0);
            });
         });
```

In this i have set a alert on scroll, but its not working but its working after manual refresh of page.

Dont know whats the reason? Any help.

PS: the div's CSS property of position is "absolute" - Does this anything to do with the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is somewhere else, the following jsfiddle works without problems http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/jBeE6/

```
<div  data-role="page" id="one" data-theme="a" >
    <div  data-role="content" id="content">        
       <script type="text/javascript" >    
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#content').bind('scroll', function () {  
                console.log("Here it is");
            });
         });
        </script>
        Here is a lot of content... a lot more goes here       
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the problem and fixed by changing the `$('#content').bind('scroll', function ()` as `$('div:jqmData(role="content")').bind('scroll', function() `.